# Generate all combinations from a List in python

Tags: python, combinations

Is there any simpler way to do this, which is less messy

```
array = []
for i in [True, False]:
    for j in [True, False]:
        for k in [True, False]:
            for l in [True, False]:
                for m in [True, False]:
                    for n in [True, False]:
                        for o in [True, False]:
                            tup = (i,j,k,l,m,n,o)
                            array.append(tup)
print (len(array))               
for tup in array:
    print (tup)
```

this gives me a list of size 128 which has all the combinations of (true,false,false..) combination.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html - note to find that all you have to do is search for __python combinations__ - very many questions can be answered by searching first.

Comment: In fact using a popular search engine with the words __generate all combinations from a list python__ gives a gazillion results. Did you try searching? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks @barny. I am unsure that stackoverflow guide lines tell to not post a question if you find it on "popular search engine". I checked this website where I did not get an answer so I asked the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
from itertools import combinations

result = set(combinations((True, False) * 7, 7))

for tup in result:
  print(tup)

print(f"TOTAL: {len(result)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `itertools.product` for this.

```py
import itertools
print(list(itertools.product(*[(True,False)]*7)))
```